# Converting old Mailer to Rails 3 (multipart/mixed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm having some difficulties converting this old mailer api to rails 3:

> content_type    "multipart/mixed"
>
> ```
> part :content_type => "multipart/alternative" do |alt|
>
>   alt.part "text/plain" do |p|
>      p.body = render_message("summary_report.text.plain.erb",
> ```
>
> :message =>
>   message.gsub(/<.*br.*>/,"\n"),
>   :campaign=>campaign,
>   :aggregate=>aggregate,
>   :promo_messages=>campaign.participating_promo_msgs)
>          end
>
> ```
>    alt.part "text/html" do |p|
>       p.body = render_message("summary_report.text.html.erb",
> ```
>
> :message => message,
>   :campaign=>campaign,
>   :aggregate=>aggregate,:promo_messages=>campaign.participating_promo_msgs)
>          end
>
> ```
> end
> if bounce_path
>   attachment :content_type => "text/csv",
>   :body=> File.read(bounce_path),
>   :filename => "rmo_bounced_emails.csv"
> end
> attachment :content_type => "application/pdf",
>       :body => File.read(report_path),
>       :filename=>"rmo_report.pdf"
> ```

In particular I don't understand how to differentiate the different multipart options. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Action Mailer will automatically send multipart emails if you have different templates for the same action."
For example having these files would give you text and html versions:

```
summary_report.text.erb
summary_report.html.erb
```

Check the Rails Guides for details:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-multipart-emails
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-emails-with-attachments